# Nagios: Host goes Down -> Up after that all Services seems to timeout

Tags: service, host, nagios

i have a strange Problem with Nagios. After restart everything runs perfectly fine.
Then some hours later, Hosts are shown down and a minute later up again(see History log below). After that all Services fail with a timeout.

This doesn´t happen with all Servers at the same time. It seems rather randomly which Server fails.

**History log:**

```
[2013-06-26 19:19:07] SERVICE ALERT: HyperV 1;Check CPU HyperV 1;CRITICAL;SOFT;1;CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 120 seconds.
[2013-06-26 19:17:27] HOST ALERT: HyperV 1;UP;SOFT;2;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 3.01 ms
[2013-06-26 19:16:17] HOST ALERT: HyperV 1;DOWN;SOFT;1;PING CRITICAL - Packet loss = 100%
```

**What i have tried so far.**

-Increased the timeouts

-Changed the Host check, so that it get checked more often before fail (5 times instead of 1)

-Executed the scripts from command line -> Also fail (maybe Ubuntu problem?)

-Checked Logs on both sides for errors (nothing found)

After a restart everything is fine again.

**System Infos:**

-Nagios is running on an Ubuntu 13.04

-Some clients are running different Windows with NSClient++

-ESX with Versions from 4.0 to 5.1

**Plugins:**

-check_nrpe

-check_vmfs from [Nagios Exchange](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/%2a-Virtual-Environments/VMWare/check_vmfs-2Esh--2D-Check-vmfs-datastores-through-VMware-VCLI/details)

I sth. is unclear don´t hesitate to ask.

Thx & Best,

Pille

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a networking issue, not a Nagios issue.  Possibly a bad cable, failing NIC, routing problem, switch flapping, arp table overflow, could be any number of things.

Since this affects all hosts/services, and intermittently, and clears itself up, I would suggest you  start looking for a problem on your local connections first.  If it only affects some items and not others, then find which hosts have common network components and check there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All Servers are in the same Network. But yesterday i switched off ssl for the failing servers and now all seems to be fine. I will also check our infrastructure to eliminate the possibility of failures from this side.

Comment: If SSL has been the issue, possibly you are running out of entropy for the SSL random number generator and it is blocking?  Make sure you have SSL using /dev/urandom and not /dev/random...

Comment: Mhhh it seems that this dont work neither. I think i have to switch off SSL completly... As it is only for intern use this shouldnt be a problem. Thank you very much for your help